# Apache 2.2 RewriteCond on QUERY_STRING to check duplicate keys

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm desperately looking for a solution to Forbid access when the QUERY_STRING contains the duplicate key **config**.

In my Apache 2.2 configuration I have 2 VirtualHost:
customerA.mydomain.com and customerB.mydomain.com

In each VirtualHost I redirect the URL **/my_site** to a common Servlet with the customer **config** parameter:

customerA.mydomain.com/my_site -> /my_servlet?config=CUSTOMER_A
customerB.mydomain.com/my_site -> /my_servlet?config=CUSTOMER_B

In my VirtualHost customerA.mydomain.com, I added these lines to add the **config** parameter and check that the user has not added it by itself:

```
# Redirect /my_site to /my_servlet with the customer configuration.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my_site
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !config= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/my_site(/)?$ /my_servlet?config=CUSTOMER_A [PT,NC,QSA]

# Check that the CONFIG parameter match the customer.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (config=CUSTOMER_A){1} [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (config=.*){2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^/forms/frmservlet - [F]
```

It seems to work but I want to be sure that it is the right solution ?

Can I improve (If it is better) the RewriteCond by including the key separator in my RegEx ? 
For ex: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ((.*(?:^|&))config=((?:&|$).*)){2,} [NC]`

Further more, I would like to know why the following doesn't work: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (config=){2,} [NC]`

Regards,